# Type of tensor under transformation: covariant vector vs. scalar

Tags: tensors, transformation

I have some confusion regarding covariant vectors vs.  scalars under coordinate transformations. It probably has to do with what it means to "undergo a coordinate transformation".

Under a coordinate transformation, a covariant vector has components that transform in the same way as the basis vectors. And a scalar is a quantity that is invariant under coordinate transformation. For example, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors

Consider a specific point on a manifold, and an object $\partial_0 \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}$. When transformed to the primed coordinates, $\partial_{0} \rightarrow \partial_{0'} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{0'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} $. So it appears that $\partial_0$ transforms as a covariant vector. This seems to make sense, because $\partial_0$ is a part of the standard basis of the tangent space at that point, so it should transform as a basis vector.

However, the same object can be written as $\partial_0 = V^\mu \partial_\mu$, where $V^0=1$ and the other 3 components of $V^\mu$ are zero. This is evidently an invariant scalar, because we have raised and lowered indices that are matched. So $\partial_0$ should be a scalar and there seems to be a contradiction.

I think the issue is whether we want to insist that the object $\partial_0$ should remain invariant under coordinate transformation. If we do insist that it must be invariant, then $V^{\mu'}$ must adjust themselves to ensure that $V^{\mu'} \partial_{\mu'} = V^\mu \partial_\mu$. The alternative is that we think of $\partial_0$ as an element in the unprimed basis set, whose role is to span the tangent space. So then in the primed coordinate system there will be a primed basis set whose role is to span the tangent space, and the transformation is supposed to express $\partial_{0'}$ as a linear combination of the unprimed basis vectors. So in this case, the new transformed object $\partial_{0'}$ is **not** the same as the original $\partial_0$, and so $\partial_0$ transforms as a covariant vector.

Is this understanding correct, or is something else wrong?

Comment: The **n** coordinate vectors $\partial_j$ constitute a basis of the **n**-dimensional tangent space $T_p(M)$ at each point $p\in M$. The element $V^\mu \partial_\mu$ is by definition a member of the vector space $T_p(M)$, not a scalar. You need to form an inner product. You can't contract the *components* of a vector with the basis.

Comment: Thanks very much. I interpret this as: In an inner product space, requiring a 1-form to map an arbitrary vector to an invariant scalar is equivalent to requiring the inner product of two transformed vectors to be equal to the inner product of the two original vectors (this is the definition of Lorentz transforms). And so this makes sense only when there is an inner product involved. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, for example, for two vectors $V$ and $W$ using the metric you can make one of them an 1-form. Study $V^\alpha \partial_\alpha$ and $W^\beta \partial_\beta$, use the Lorenz metric $\eta_{\alpha_\beta}$ to form the invariant expression (index notation and components only, no basis) $\eta_{\alpha_\beta}V^\alpha W^\beta=V^\alpha W_\alpha$ which is the equivalent of the inner product $<V,W>$. Here we used the "lowering the index"-rule of the metric on $W$ that is $\eta_{\alpha\beta}W^\beta=W_\alpha$

Comment: @ContraKinta could you please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it as an answer?